# Why is this program giving strange output. When 6 is entered 54 is printed out,0 gets 48 printed

Tags: java

```
package another;

import java.io.IOException;

class myClass{

    public static void main(string[]args) throws IOException    
    { 
        //TODO Auto-generated method stub 
        int a =System.in.read();
        System.out.println(a);

    }
}
```

Comment: You might want to take a look at http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);a = scan.nextInt();  scan.close();
      System.out.println("The number entered by user: "+a);. What you need here is this cause yours prints out the ascii value and not the int.

Comment: @arundeep chohan thanks a lot.

Comment: @azurefrog thanks too